# authenticate using OAuth + SAML bearer flow (invalid assertion)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to authenticate using OAuth + SAML bearer flow (http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm)

But i am stuck at the point where i am getting invalid assertion error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"}
```

Here's my assertion:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="C625490D-C2B9-15BE-6DFA-7286288D9655" IssueInstant="2012-04-04T06:54:14Z" Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer>3MVG9Y6d_Btp4.....d0jnN</saml:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#C625490D-C2B9-15BE-6DFA-7286288D9655">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
          <ds:DigestValue>f187DeCiwFhhH2etlU+5byskey4=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>
MIID6zCCAtOgAwI...........4qbvd3sxAQmkhR98FSsQixMI+bTHq9zRgeFu6W5GWsun3tmqNE=
</ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">org2@dot.com
      </saml:NameID>
      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData Recipient="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" NotOnOrAfter="2012-11-20T06:35:42Z"/>
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2012-11-19T06:34:42Z" NotOnOrAfter="2012-11-20T06:35:42Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2012-11-20T06:35:42Z" SessionIndex="ED868FE5-841D-5192-766C-941A60D6602F">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
```

And here's how i am making the request:

```
curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -H "Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'" -d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer" -d "assertion=`cat saml-assertion.base64`"
```

I have properly encoded the assertion to base64url (previously i was getting error regarding invalid chars in assertion, which i fixed)

Please advice me what/where I can check further on this to know why my assertion is invalid!
PS: Everything is copied from above url's sample assertion, and username,issuer and certificate are changed by me. Also I am setting the NotBefore as the exact login time of the user.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am currently facing this same issue and this post has been around for almost a year now.

Answer (score -1):

Grant type value needs to be encoded as well, when you are sending that.
urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Asaml2-bearer

Saml assertion needs to be single assertion. It needs to be Base64 encoded as you did and then remove padding or urlencode again.

> The value of the "assertion" parameter MUST contain a single SAML 2.0
> Assertion.  The SAML Assertion XML data MUST be encoded using
> base64url, where the encoding adheres to the definition in Section 5
> of RFC 4648 [RFC4648] and where the padding bits are set to zero.  To
> avoid the need for subsequent encoding steps (by "application/
> x-www-form-urlencoded" [W3C.REC-html401-19991224], for example), the
> base64url encoded data SHOULD NOT be line wrapped and pad characters
> ("=") SHOULD NOT be included.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-17#section-2.1

Send with post encoded values:

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Asaml2-bearer&
assertion=PHNhbWxwOl...[omitted]...ZT4

Comment: Don't think this will work. urlencoding the grant_type throws "grant type not supported" error.